# Flutter run multiple http request take much time

Tags: api, flutter, request

I want to ask about increase performance when i do multiple future http request in single page. In case , i want to build a dashboard page. In dashboard, i've 4 endpoints url that return different result in every endpoint and should be shown in dashboard page.

here example code when load data

```
var client = new http.Client();

Future main() async {

  var newProducts = await client.get("${endpoint}/product?type=newly&limit=5");

  ProductListResponse newProductResponse = ProductListResponse.fromJson(json.decode(newProducts.body));

  var bestSeller = await client.get("${endpoint}/product?type=best-seller&limit=5");

  ProductListResponse bestSellerResponse = ProductListResponse.fromJson(json.decode(bestSeller.body));

  var outOfStock = await client.get("${endpoint}/product?type=out-of-stock&limit=5");

  ProductListResponse outOfStockResponse = ProductListResponse.fromJson(json.decode(outOfStock.body));

  var lastRequest = await client.get("${endpoint}/product-request?type=newly&limit=5");

  ProductRequestListResponse productRequestResponse = ProductRequestListResponse.fromJson(json.decode(lastRequest.body));
}
```

every endpoint when i hit manually using postman it takes 200ms for return the result. But when i implement in flutter app, it took almost 2s.

can i improve performance when getting data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why your code run so slow is that you are making those HTTP requests **one by one**. Each `await` will take quite some time.

You can either not use `await` and implement the logic using callbacks (`.then`) or you can combine the Futures into one using [Future.wait](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.6.1/dart-async/Future/wait.html) and use `await` for that combined Future.

Your code will look something like this:

```
var responses = await Future.wait([
  client.get("${endpoint}/product?type=newly&limit=5"),
  client.get("${endpoint}/product?type=best-seller&limit=5"),
  client.get("${endpoint}/product?type=out-of-stock&limit=5"),
  client.get("${endpoint}/product-request?type=newly&limit=5")
]);
```

Comment: I wonder how will you fetch the response of each get Request?Will the responses variable be a list? If so I would recommend it to be named as ```List<dynamic> responses``` for better readability and to be precise.

Comment: Yes, the responses will be a list, you can get individual result using list index. list[0], list[1]...